# How to write and execute a hello world program in file for R?

Tags: linux, r

I did look in here: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#R-Programming

Wikipedia shows how to write an on the fly R program: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hello_world_program_examples#R_2

**But how to execute this from a file?

What extension needs to be given?

How to compile the file then?**

on Linux.

---

I created a file `mow.R` containing the following code:
`cat ('Hello world!')`

R says:

```
> source mow.R
Error: unexpected symbol in "source mow.R"
```

Comment: See my answer and example, it should be `source("mow.R")`, you can also use single quotes. `source()` is a function.

Comment: This is described in the R manual at http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#Executing-commands-from-or-diverting-output-to-a-file

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I general you want to give your R files the `.R` extension.

To run a program you can start R (by typing "R" at the command prompt) and once inside the program/interpreter, you can execute your program (let's call it `"so.R"`) with the source command. E.g.,

```
> source('so.R')
```

yields:

```
Hello World
```

You can run the program from the Unix shell with

```
R CMD BATCH so.R
```

it will generate a file named `"so.Rout"` that will contain the output of your program run, especially if it contains non-trivial amounts of output. If there is a problem with the program run, the error messages etc will also be in this file so it's a good diagnostic tool. An alternative is the [Rscript](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rscript) command which sends its output to stdout, in which case if it's long you need to capture it yourself.

There is a very useful trick, when googling for R related topics it can be tricky because R is a single character. To be effective, pre-pend "**r-help:**" to your search terms. E.g.,

> `r-help:Running a program`

Here are two manuals that might be useful/help you get started:

- [Introduction to R](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html)
- [Programming in R](http://manuals.bioinformatics.ucr.edu/home/programming-in-r)

and also take a look at [The R Manuals](http://cran.r-project.org/manuals.html).

More information/FAQs, etc., can be found at the [R web site](http://cran.r-project.org/) itself.  I have found that there is a *lot* of information on R (esp tutorials etc), but it can be tricky to find them. The "r-help" google trick really helps with this.

Comment: that's helpful, now. Thanks. Is that information somewhere in the R website?

Comment: Yes, *lots* of information on the web page, but I agree with it, it's not the easiest to navigate. I put some links etc in my post.

Answer (score 17):

You could also try:

```
Rscript mow.R
```

to get output on the console.